# Create an instagram chatbot calling an external API

Tags: instagram, chatbot

I've already made an online API which takes some text as input and give an answer as text. It is based on a ML generative algorithm which find the end of the input sentence.

Now I want to create a chatbot (ideally on instagram) and make it call this external API, whatever the input text is

```
user> "Hello"
bot> "Hello my name is bot"
```

What is the simplest way to do this ? Can I do it for free ?

I've tried DialogFlow but I'm a bit lost, I'm new with chatbots...